# DropdownList's selectedValue doesn't get affected with value from DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

This problem has been driving me crazy and Monday mornings don't really help.

I'm loading 2 dropdownboxes like so:

- This one gets its selectedvalue affected by the db value

  ```
  <dd><%= Html.DropDownList("type", New SelectList(ViewData("typeList"), 
      "value", "text", Model.type), New With {.class = ""})%></dd>
  ```
- This one ignores the value loaded in the model and always displays the first value in the dropdownbox

  ```
  <dd><%= Html.DropDownList("action", New SelectList(ViewData("actionList"), 
      "value", "text", Model.action), New With {.class = ""})%></dd>
  ```

I've already debugged this page and Model.Action comes loaded with the correct values but they never get assigned to the selectedvalue.

**EDIT:**

This is the ActionResult which displays the page:

```
<Authorize()> _
        Public Function Edit(ByVal id As Guid) As ActionResult
            Dim article As Article_Ad = articleAdRepository.GetById(id)

            ViewData("actionList") = GetActionValues()
            ViewData("typeList") = GetTypeValues()

            Return View(article)
        End Function
```

And these are the functions which feed the dropdownboxes:

```
Private Function GetTypeValues() As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
            Dim list As New List(Of SelectListItem)
            Dim sel As SelectListItem

            'Imagem
            sel = New SelectListItem
            sel.Text = "Imagem"
            sel.Value = "image"
            list.Add(sel)

            'Video
            sel = New SelectListItem
            sel.Text = "Video"
            sel.Value = "video"
            list.Add(sel)

            Return list
        End Function

        Private Function GetActionValues() As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
            Dim list As New List(Of SelectListItem)
            Dim sel As SelectListItem

            ' Call browser window
            sel = New SelectListItem
            sel.Text = "Mostrar Janela"
            sel.Value = 1
            list.Add(sel)

            ' Play fullscreen video
            sel = New SelectListItem
            sel.Text = "Mostrar Video em FullScreen"
            sel.Value = 2
            list.Add(sel)

            ' Show fullscreen picture
            sel = New SelectListItem
            sel.Text = "Mostrar Imagem em FullScreen"
            sel.Value = 3
            list.Add(sel)

            Return list
        End Function
```

Comment: Can we see the code that generates the SelectList's you pass to your view?

Comment: @David, I've added the info you requested to my post. Thanks.

Comment: Just a clarification on the problem--you're expecting the two dropdown lists to have selected values set, correct? My VB may be a bit rusty, but where are you *setting* the selected value?

Comment: If you look at my aspx code, inside the declaration of each dropdown I'm declaring a new SelectList and specifying in the constructor that the value contained inside Model.type and Model.action, specifically, are the selectedvalues. It's working perfectly well for the "type" dropdown, just not for action.

Comment: Another clarification--your second dropdown's selected value is `Model.Action` and you may have suggested it's actually `Model.action` (lowercase spelling). Was this intentional or is it a typo?

Comment: It's a typo, will correct it on my main post asap. The actual name is really Model.action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer to this question and I feel slightly ashamed for the final result, to be honest.
It seems that I was using the name "action" in a ViewData variable which made it conflict with the dropdownbox's name "action". 
After changing the ViewData to "actions" (added the "s") it stopped doing conflict and assigned the selectedvalue correctly.

My tip to anyone running into the same problem as me is to make sure there's no other control making use of the same name you are assigning to your object, just to be on the safe side.

Thanks to everyone for the pointers here.

Comment: I thought I remembered reading something about a similar problem. If this is your fix, be sure to mark it as the answer and maybe elaborate a little or give a quick code sample.

Comment: I will mark it as the answer as soon as stackoverflow allows me (2 days after you answer your own question) and I shall elaborate more on it when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try setting the correct `SelectListItem.Selected` value? I am assuming the `Imagem` item is supposed to be selected below.

```
Private Function GetTypeValues() As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
    Dim list As New List(Of SelectListItem)
    Dim sel As SelectListItem

    'Imagem
    sel = New SelectListItem
    sel.Text = "Imagem"
    sel.Value = "image"
    sel.Selected = True ' This line has been added
    list.Add(sel)
    '...

    Return list
End Function
```

Comment: Functions like GetTypeValues, in this situation work solely to fill the IEnumerable that will feed the dropdownbox. Inside the dropdown constructor, it is specified which value will be selected.
E.g.: Model.action may contain the values 1, 2 and 3. Depending on what values is loaded from the database (and it loads correctly, I debugged it) the value of the selectlist gets selected.

Comment: @Hallaghan My mistake. I missed a set of parentheses in your `SelectList` constructor and thought it may have been part of the Html.DropDownList override (then I realized there is no override with five arguments) ;)

Comment: Well, after debugging a little more I noticed something rather weird in my tests: The below dropdownbox won't get its selectedvalue assigned <%= Html.DropDownList("action", New SelectList(ViewData("actionList"), "Value", "Text", Model.action), New With {.class = ""})%> But the following one will <%= Html.DropDownList("s_action", New SelectList(ViewData("actionList"), "Value", "Text", Model.action), New With {.class = ""})%> If I change the id of the dropdownbox to s_action rather than action, it will work as intended. The problem is the id but I don't understand why...

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a similar approach to you where I build out the SelectList in my viewmodel and reference it from my views with Html.DropDownList.

One big difference is that I always set my value/text parameters to string values even if the corresponding data is int.

Example (C# - sorry):

```
private List<SelectListItem> widgets;

public List<SelectListItem> Widgets
{
  get
  {
    if (widgets == null)
    {
      widgets = new List<SelectListItem>();
      widgets.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "10", Text = "10" });
      widgets.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "25", Text = "25" });
      widgets.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "50", Text = "50" });
      widgets.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "100", Text = "100" });
      widgets.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "500", Text = "500" });
    }
    return widgets;
  }
  private set { }
}
```

Another difference although I doubt it is responsible for this problem is that I strongly type my views to a view model and then I access the view model's SelectList property directly from the view vs. assigning it to viewdata in the controller.  It looks like you bound your view directly to the entity (i.e. the domain model).

Comment: I tried that approach after reading your answer but it still doesn't recognize the value of "action" solely. (and I actually prefer code examples in C# as that is my language of choice, I'm doing VB.NET for a short time)

Comment: I noticed your Model reference is Model.Action and the DDL is bound to "action" - have you tried binding it to "Action" instead?  Just a thought.

Comment: Well, after debugging a little more I noticed something rather weird in my tests:
The below dropdownbox won't get its selectedvalue assigned

<%= Html.DropDownList("action", New SelectList(ViewData("actionList"), "Value", "Text", Model.action), New With {.class = ""})%>

But the following one will

<%= Html.DropDownList("s_action", New SelectList(ViewData("actionList"), "Value", "Text", Model.action), New With {.class = ""})%>

If I change the id of the dropdownbox to s_action rather than action, it will work as intended. The problem is the id but I don't understand why...